# How to use date in sed command on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, date, sed

I need to replace **{{date}}** string in a file, with current date time (date command) in mac os.
I usually use *sed* command in Ubuntu, but it doesn't work in MacOs. I tried many things but didn't work.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
sed -i '' 's/{{date}}/\``date``/g' file.xml
```

But sed isn't evaluating date command as I expected.
How can I evaluate DATE command in sed on Mac Os X? (Using Mountain Lion, but I guess it doesn't matter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to enclose sed subtitution between `"` instead of single `'`:

This can work:

```
$ echo "hellodatehere" | sed "s/date/`date`/"
helloMon Apr 22 16:49:35 CEST 2013here
```

In your case:

```
sed -i "s/{{date}}/`date`/g" file.xml
```

In case you want to parse the date a little bit, you can do:

```
date_value=`date "+%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"`
sed -i "s/{{date}}/$date_value/g" file.xml
```

Comment: Hi fedorqui. Thank you four your help. I also tried with set -i..., but I was using single quotes. Now it works. Thanks a lot.